# How to debug pppd without syslog.conf file in linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, syslog

I'm a new linux learner then sorry if I ask a basic question.

I'm working with pppd (writing script to pass it by command pppd call my_script, refer to https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2109) but new ppp0 couldn't be created as expectation.

I would like to check for log to observer what's literally done. Normally we can take a look at /etc/syslog.conf rsyslog.conf then /var/log/messages but syslog.conf or rsyslog.conf is not available somehow then /var/log/messages is empty.

So my question is how could I check and enable syslog report? Are there any different way to observe what pppd truly done?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Your Linux probably used systemd, check logs with `sudo journalctl -f`.

Comment: Thanks Luis. You make my day. Btw, how do u know it's systemd?

Comment: One of the symptoms of its presence is that `/var/log/messages` is empty ;-)

Comment: Thank Luis. I'm reading about systemd. ;)